# Как получить дату от Dialog и по ней создать item в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-dialog

У меня есть стандартный RecyclerView, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку(fab) выскакивал мой кастомный диалог, я вводил информацию и на основе этого создавался новый экземпляр в recyclerView. Вопрос в том, как мне это реализовать? Что мне нужно использовать? Уже голову поломал и не знаю как получить данные из диалога и потом создать на их основе экземляр модели. Разьясните, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно где именно проблема... Примерно так можно сделать:

1. создаем интерфейс OnItemAdded с методом onItemAdded(Item item), реализуем его внутри нашего RrecyclerView
2. fab при создании диалога отдает ему экземпляр OnItemAdded
3. диалог в случае успешного создания объекта отдает его в метод onItemAdded

Если проблема именно с реализацией метода onItemAdded, то подскажу что менять адаптер не стоит, лучше вызывать notifyDatasetChanged или notifyItemInserted